# How to update PowerBi Web which contains python code?

Tags: python, powerbi, refresh, powerbi-desktop, gateway

I have a panel built in PowerBi Desktop, which contains a code in python, I published the panel, but I can't update it, even having installed and configured Data Gateway.
How to update Power Bi web?
Also, how to create automatic updates?

I need my panel in power bi web to be updated and run the python code.

Answer (score 0):

If the Python is [used in Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-in-query-editor) it can only be refreshed using a Personal-mode Gateway.

> Once you upload the .pbix file to the Power BI service, a couple more
> steps are necessary to enable data to refresh in the service and to
> enable visuals to be updated in the service. The data needs access to
> Python for visuals to be updated. The other steps are the following
> steps:
>
> Enable scheduled refresh for the dataset. To enable scheduled refresh
> for the workbook that contains your dataset with Python scripts, see
> Configuring scheduled refresh, which also includes information about
> Personal Gateway. Install the Personal Gateway. You need a Personal
> Gateway installed on the machine where the file is located, and where
> Python is installed. The Power BI service must access that workbook
> and re-render any updated visuals. For more information, see install
> and configure Personal Gateway.

Comment: Hi David, tanks for answer.
I installed and configured the Personal Gateway on the machine that has Python and from which I operate Power Bi Desktop.
But with all the configurations done and the Python path pointed, I can't configure the credentials to run the update.
See the image.
Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myniq.png